# Cant disable touchpad on ASUS F555L

Tags: touchpad, asus

I have just bought an ASUS F555L laptop and obviously no linux driver is available for the touchpad and I cant disable it from the settings. In fact, it is not even in the settings. Any ideas why? or if there is a work-around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You type this into your terminal this to see the running devices.
If it's not seen there, it's definitely a driver issue.
If you're trying to disable the driver, do this :

```
xinput list
```

It'll list the running devices.  You can disable it by

```
xinput disable [devicename/ID]
```

The devicename is something kinda like *ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad*, but I find disabling it by the device ID easier.

Note: This will be re-enabled after a system restart.  It's good if you plan on re-enabling it sometime soon, but not necessarily *right now*. 
(I sometimes carry a small book on my computer... I disable the keyboard temporarily since I don't use it, because who wants a tiny book repeatedly smashing the 'k' key?)

Here's some more information on [xinput](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input) if you have any other questions about how to use it.

The reason why it possibly not show up, or possibly may have an error is most likely that it's possibly not supported by the kernel yet, or some sort of driver error.

There is a similar issue noted [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253069) which completely fixed their similar issue.  The person on the other thread had specific drivers to fix their touchpad, however.

- [Focaltech touchpad drivers](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/07642x3lziqgmz9/AACGWNO5_lNnX7x7tYMoH9gka?dl=0)
- [Other information on related bugs with Focaltech](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1323371)

(To spare you scrolling time, it was fixed in `linux-generic-lts-wily` package.)

If there's something that I missed, comment and I'll respond as soon as I can.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I could disable the touchpad with that commmand of yours, but is there a way to make it permanent? The moment I restart, it is reset.

Comment: thanks for the answer. That post is almost a year old....I dont know if it is okay for newer kernel versions or for the laptop that I have. By the way.....do you know why "touchpad" indicator crashed in 15.04? I typed "touchpad-indicator" to check what causes to crash it, but it wont start. It says command not found

Comment: @Elysium You could try using 'sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf' and disabling the drivers from there.

Comment: @Elysium Sorry for the late reply, schoolwork caught up to me.  Let me know if that doesn't work - I know there are a few other ways to do it.

Comment: @Elysium You can also change it in 'startup application preferences' and remove it from there.

Comment: @Elysium I'm not quite sure why the 'touchpad' indicator crashed in 15.04.  Maybe it's not installed if the command isn't found, or they have some replacement software.  [I tend to use Fedora, but I have Ubuntu / Arch on my chromebook].

Comment: @Elysium http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/atareao_atareao/wily/main/base/touchpad-indicator

Comment: hi there. School is more important. :) So...no worries. I have just tried the deb that I downloaded. Installed it using the software center, but it keep crashing. I type "toucpad-indicator" and it keeps telling me "command not found". Really weird. Do you know how to install it from the ppa?

Comment: @Elysium  You can install from the ppa directly using ' sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<ppa_name> '

Comment: @Elysium After that, you can install touchpad-indicator from the command line as you would before.  [I've never liked using the Software center anyway xD]

Comment: @Elysium If you have any other preferred means of communication that you wouldn't mind disclosing to an internet stranger, I'll take you up on it~!  I respond much faster by other means.  I apologize for the wait.

Comment: hi there. Dont worry. The upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10 has sorted it out. Now it works just fine and I can disable it easily from the settings. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Oh, okay!  Glad it got fixed! @Elysium